# CRM 2011 - Lookup using Connections

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In my entity I have an Account lookup field and a Contact lookup field.  The user selects an Account and then hits the lookup on the Contact field.

Is there a way to use Views and/or  Related Record Filtering in order to present a list showing Contacts with a Connection to the Account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [addCustomView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51828fe3-f6ff-4f97-80ed-b06b3a354955#BKMK_getDefaultView#BKMK_addCustomView) method. What you need is:

- get accountid and build fetch xml to list related contacts
- add custom view to contact lookup

There is good example on the linked page hbow to use it in practice.